# Boot-repair failing on 12.04 dual boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

After reinstalling 12.04 on my machine alongside Windows 7 I got the grub rescue prompt.  Following from other posts on here I installed and ran boot repair.  However it seems to be running into some problems,  here is the paste output of the boot-repair:

*

Any suggestions would be appreciated

<sub>*The link is no longer valid and has been removed on edit.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Something is blocking grub-install (out of memory error).

1. Please make sure that your BIOS is setup to boot on the Ubuntu disk.
2. Run `Boot-Repair`, UPDATE IT, click "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB options" tab, tick the "Purge GRUB" option, apply, and indicate the new URL that will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Either I don't understand the log or it looks like it wouldn't work.

For /dev/sda, which I assume is the drive you are trying to boot from, grub2 would be loaded from the second and following sectors of the drive, but it then looks for the grub configuration from /boot/config in the NTFS (windows) partition. /dev/sdb uses the msdos specifier even though there aren't any Microsoft formatted partitions on that drive.

As something to try, I'd suggest reinstalling grub on your boot disk having it boot from Ubuntu on /dev/sdb1.